# $\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(3x-4)e^x$ solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(3x-4)e^x$

Just i need method. I know what I do is not nice but I just want a method of what to do.

Comment: Thank you! I will delete my post.

Comment: Yes. I know the post is against the rules. I got what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the integrating factor is $e^{-x}.$

So you multiplying through by $e^{-x}$ we have $$e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx}-e^{-x}y=\frac{d}{dx}(ye^{-x})=(3x-4)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thanks you! I will delete my post now.

Comment: No need to delete, just upvote and hit the tick to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-y=(3x-4)e^x$$
Another solution is to  first solve the homogeneous equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-y=0$$
$$r-1=0 \implies r=1 \implies y_h=Ce^x$$
And solve the inhomogeneous DE.
$$y_p=x(Ax+B)e^x$$
Find the constants $A$ and $B$.